# Accessing Ruby objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails app (4.1.8) that requires a lot of javascript in my show view, and I need a way to access data returned from ActiveRecord within the actual js file

Here's an example:

My Show controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

now i need to access this data in my show javascript, but this is the only way i could do it:

My Show view

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    var myEmail = "<%= j @user.email %>";
    // do stuff with myEmail
<% end %>
```

My question is, is there a way I can render this javascript or include it in a separate script tag while maintaining the userdata? I don't want to have to write hundreds of lines of jQuery and js inside this javascript_tag and it's painful to debug. Everything I've tried so far (putting it in the asset pipeline, rendering a seperate .js.erb file) just turns myEmail into a string with the ruby statement inside it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add a semicolon after myEmail declaration, but it's there in my actual code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

03-02-2016 21:10: Alright, got a working example - Dibbz to [Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) - he was right, parsing to valid JSON isn't even required, when calling `.to_json` on a ruby object it will print a valid JS object literal instead. <strike>Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/SidOfc/accessing-ruby-objects-in-js) with working examples, if you'd like to clone it and use the code - feel free and have a nice day! (examples are built with Rails)</strike>

---

Aside from Øle Bjarnstroem's answer which implies the use of AJAX, if you want to use a model in JS you could do something like this

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
    var user = <%= @user.to_json %>;
<% end %>
```

Now the JS variable `user` holds all the properties that the model has as well since it simply converts the ruby object <strike>to JSON</strike> directly to a JS object.

- [Rails `to_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

#### EDIT

As for not having to write the JS, you could create a helper for it - this would still inject the JS into your page but you could just supply an object as an argument to this function and then simply output that in your code with 1 call instead of doing the `javascript_tag do ... end` construct.

There are multiple ways to go about with this, you could use Rails' `content_for` to set and get content that will be rendered in your head.

e.g.

**helper**

```
module myHelper

    def obj_as_js_var(var_name, obj, content_name = nil)
        output_tag = javascript_tag("var #{var_name} = #{obj.to_json};".html_safe, type: 'text/javascript')
        # if content_name is set, use content_for instead of directly printing the tag inline
        if content_name
            content_for content_name, output_tag
        else
            output_tag
        end
    end
end
```

Now when using this helper in your view

**view**

```
<%= obj_as_js_var('user', @user) %>
# ... rest of page
```

Will render the same output on a single line, the first argument (`'user'` in this case) is the name the variable will have, the second argument (`@user`) will be converted to JSON.

**But wait a moment...** what If I want it in the `<head>` of the document?

Well, the helper has an optional third argument which, if supplied will return the value of `content_for` and it will set the tag in the content.

So if, in your *layout.erb* you have something like

**layout**

```
<head>
   <!-- ... snipped -->
   <%= content_for :javascript if content_for? :javascript %>
</head>
```

You could use the following in your view instead (notice we're not rendering anything with `<%=` but using `<%` instead as we're saving the content for use in the `<head>`)

```
<% obj_as_js_var('user', @user, :javascript) %>
```

Now, the `content_for :javascript` in the head of your layout will render the output there, always. Note that if the content_for `:javascript` is loaded *after* the *application.js* then you won't have the data available there!

Comment: This should work. I usually follow similar approach when dealing with the data that needs to be rendered in front-end. There are couple other ways that I am aware of, but this sure is the simplest of them all. +1

Comment: @v1p and the one that requires the least effort since it's effectively a oneliner to convert a ruby AR object to a JS object usable in view ;)

Comment: This isn't what i was asking, I'm already doing stuff like that here. (I had THAT problem a few weeks ago) my question was how to I extrapulate the content inside <%= javascript_tag do %> into a separate js file so it's less obtrusive (while still getting access to the @user from the initial GET request to show )

Comment: @rhenvar, quote: "My question is, is there a way I can **render this javascript** *or* **include it in a separate script tag** while maintaining the userdata?" - this seems to be exactly what you're asking, I'm just replying to the first option since it's the most simple solution, if this is indeed not what you're looking for then please specify what it is that you want exactly by editing your uestion

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. What I meant was could I run that javascript without using the javascript_tag where i have to write raw javascript in the html.erb, I'd like to write it in a separate file

Comment: @rhenvar see updated answer, I hope this comes closer to what you are looking for. P.S. I don't normally work with ERB so I'm not sure if the supplied code will actually run but this should be a matter of checking some errors while outputting.

Comment: No need to do the round-tripping. Just do `var user = <%= @user.to_json %>`. It's already a JSON string, will be parsed by JS engine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying here, this will render JSON in the variable `user` yes, but the OP also stated in a comment he wanted a cleaner solution to what he's using and also, JSON still has to be parsed to create a valid JS object to work with

Comment: Yes, it will be parsed by the JS engine when that javascript will be executed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ofcourse but you still have to change it from being a JSON string to a JS object to use for instance, `user.name` etc...

Comment: Yes, that's what javascript engines do. BTW, your snippet will emit invalid code (`JSON.parse("<%= @user.to_json %>")`). You see, `.to_json` produces double-quoted strings, as dictated by the spec. The result will be `JSON.parse("{"foo": "bar"}")`, which is not valid JS.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @rhenvar, no problem - glad I could help! If anything is wrong please let me know.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're just plain wrong. You're failing to see that `JSON.parse` actually takes a string parameter which is **exactly** what the output of the code is. the `JSON.parse` function *then and only then* returns the *valid JS code* - read the docs please.

Comment: Jeezus man, just try actually running your code, before accusing someone of something. http://pastie.org/10707040. Also, it wouldn't hurt to re-read on basics of ERB.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did note that I don't use ERB, hence the code can be faulty. Anyways - the OP's problem is solved here and when I get off work I'll make a working example using ERB - updating the answer that the code might not work when copy-pasted

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: Actually, your other solution also won't work when copy-pasted.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my comment clearly states that 'pasted code' might not work, not any specific example - also I added to that that I'll be creating a working example as I get home which is in 6 hours - check back later. - Also, you're not using `to_json` on an AR object, If I do `@user = User.last` and then `@user.to_json` I get a perfectly fine JSON string. If you're going to critique atleast prove me wrong completely, this says nothing

Comment: Sure, If you could ping me after you update, it'd be swell. :)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: to_json works the same way regardless of the original object type. a json string is a json string. Anyhow, I'll be waiting for your updated examples :)

Also, I don't even need to prove anything. Just run the code. It will prove you wrong.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will, the last bit of my comment was a bit harsh - sorry for that - anyways I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated, My apologies for my ignorance :)

Comment: Thanks for hashing this out!

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: cool, apologies accepted :) However, now part of your answer doesn't make sense. The one where you're saying "but you need JSON.parse for this or else it won't work". I suggest you clean this up, to not confuse future readers.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand: you saw my PR, I take it? Also I was preparing pretty much the same edited post as you just did.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my god - I didn't even think of directly printing an object literal instead of parsing as JSON to convert it with JS. This solution is more efficient both on client and server side! I **FINALLY** understand what you mean :)

Comment: Just came across this old gem of a comment chain, still beautiful to read as well :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var user = <%= @user.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide the data you need via a simple REST API and just request it with jQuery and then do with the result whatever you want?

In your controller, for `GET /users/:id/`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        render json: @user
    end
end
```

In jQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "/users/1", function( data ) {
  // Do something with the retrieved data
  console.log(data);
  var myEmail = data["email"];
});
```

See also [Building a RESTful API in a Rails Application](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application)

Comment: Wouldn't I still need grab the @user.id in my .js to build the URL?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you are trying to do exactly. It is the same with a traditional html view. Here you also need to know the id before even being able to fetch the user from the database. So I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Best skip an unnecessary HTTP call