# How to store in localStorage in Javascript from Ruby variable

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, local-storage

I try to store a token in my localstorage from a ruby variable, 
As I understood, you can only set LocalStorage with Javascript, 
So here is my question, how can I pass my variable from Ruby to Javascript ? I saw some answers with script tag in the view, but is there any solution to do it directly in the app.js folder ?

So here is my Controller :

```
 @token = HTTParty.post('https://test.pro/2.0/auth/token/access', 
      body: {
          client_id: XXX,
          client_secret: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
          code: LLLLLL
      }
  )
```

And in my view if I do a <%= @token %>, I have the following result :

```
{"access_token": "1VwCAjhsfCsdEoBoQs1G9kLHKoWOcJjamyj1s8_NQPrHeGNagzYYFrXKp_VlY", "token_type": "Bearer"}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform javascript from within a ruby file you can use a javascript_tag:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag

An example of how to use it:

[Accessing Ruby objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174820/accessing-ruby-objects-in-javascript)

In your case, something in your view like:

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
   localStorage.setItem('accessToken', <%= @token["access_token"] %>);
   localStorage.setItem('tokenType', <%= @token["access_token"] %>);
<% end %>
```

Should do the trick